# Can I configure Azure diagnostics on IAAS virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics

I would like to reuse libraries written for Azure PAAS solution (WebRoles and WorkerRoles) in a specific service running in Azure VM (IAAS). It would be beneficial if I could use the same trace listener (DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener) and let the Azure diagnostics to deliver logs to Azure Storage. Is it possible to install the diagnostics services into Azure VM?

I found basically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408564/is-it-possible-to-use-azure-diagnostics-without-being-in-a-hosted-service) on SO but it is quite old now. Perhaps there was some progress?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is still the same. You can't use the diagnostics libraries for PaaS in IaaS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's now possible to use the Azure Diagnostics extension with Azure IaaS virtual machines as well as PaaS cloud services, see the [Virtual Machine Monitoring with Azure Diagnostics Extension](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/02/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/) documentation for more info.